# autoFocus Directive not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a directive that didn't work in firefox (version 36.00) .

this should be the same with atuofocus attribute in html 5.

Here is the code :

```
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ounsqcmt/55/)

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: It may just be jsFiddle. [Here](http://jsbin.com/wabulevapa/1/edit?html,js,output), I pasted your exact code into jsBin and it worked.

Comment: still not working on firefox

Comment: Interesting, what version of firefox?  Works for me in nightly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, for firefox you need a workaround, wrap it in a watch:

```
    _scope.$watch('autoFocus', function (value) {
        if (value) {
            _element[0].focus();
        }
    });
```

This should definitely fix your problem.

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?